# Solving a matrix differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to solve:

$\frac{d U_t}{dt} = Tr(G^{\dagger}U_t)G - Tr(U_t^{\dagger}G)U_t G^{\dagger} U_t$

Where $U_t \in SU(4)$ and $G \in SU(4)$ is given and constant.

Is it possible to solve this equation? A solution not in coordinates would be most helpful. I've tried several series methods previously.

Comment: for $G$ hermitian and traceless I see $U=I$ as a solution.

Comment: If $n \ne 4$,how can this work? So you must mean $n = 4$, right?  Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure you have $U_tG^\dagger U_t$ instead of $U_t^\dagger G^\dagger U_t$ or $U_tG^\dagger U_t^\dagger$ on the right hand side? If so, putting $V_t=G^\dagger U_t\in SU(4)$ will simplify the equation a little bit: $\dot{V_t} = tr(V_t)I - tr(V_t^\dagger)V_t^2$.

Comment: Stating the obvious: thus there are infinitely many constant solutions, because any constant and *real* $V\in SO(4)$ with $V^2=I$ would satisfy the equation.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is as stated. Awkward as this may be, nature did it apparently.

Comment: @RobertLewis, Thank for spotting that. I've updated.

Comment: My pleasure, sir!  Cheers!

Comment: Making the transformation $U_t= G^{1/2}V_t G^{1/2}$ still results in some simplification

Comment: Yes. In either case we have $\dot{V}_t=tr(V_t)I-tr(V_t^\dagger)V_t^2$ and hence $\dot{V}_t$ commutes with $V_t$. If we pretend that (or if one can prove that) $V_t$ has differentiable eigenvectors, the formulation may become even cleaner.

Comment: We can assume that here for sure.